# How much does an LCD projector attenuate an 8000 lumen LED light source?

Tags: led, lcd, optics

I am attempting to replace a high-pressure lamp in a 3 LCD (red, green & blue) projector with a 100 W LED array. This resulted in a very disappointing (dim) projected image.

From [this stack exchange question / answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33608/how-much-heat-do-power-leds-dissipate) it appears most LEDs can produce about 80 lumen per watt. This infers the LED array is producing about 8000 lumen.

Most projectors claim producing between 2000 and 3500 lumen.  So even if the projector's red, green & blue filters and LCD shutters attenuated the LED brightness by 50%, enough light should reach the screen to create an acceptable (bright) projected image.

Comment: I think the bigger problem is that the original lamp has a very small emission area whereas the LED array has a much more dispersed area that is not going to be able to be effectively focused by the lens.

Comment: An LCD will attenuate the input light to about 5% of the incoming intensity in addition to the focussing ability of the optical system with the LED source.

Comment: I have to admit, after thinking about it, just having perfect polarizing filters in the light path will attenuate the brightness by 50%.  I should edit my question and reduce my assumption to a more reasonable value like 25%.  But only 5%?  That surprising.  Suddenly I see the brightness advantage of a DLP system.

Comment: The spectral content of a white LED is different than you original bulb.

Comment: That is a good point.  I didn't think of that.  If the dyes in the LED don't match up with the existing Red, Green & Blue filters that would attenuate the brightness even more.  Bummer.

Comment: Lumens are the wrong unit since you don't care about total light but rather how much goes into the relay optics. A huge array where most of the light misses the input doesn't help much. If you aren't going to redesign the optics, try to match the lumens/area/angle of the original bulb.

Comment: Is this a 100-watt array or a 100-watt **EQUIVALENT** array? The former consumes 100 watts of power and puts a lot/most of that into light output while the latter puts out approximately the same light output as a 100 watt incandescent and consumes around 10 watts. Big difference.

Comment: I assume that the energy consumed by the LED to produce light and heat is 100 Watts.  Also, I believe the power supply is providing about 30 Volts at about 3 Amps. Which is about 100 Watts.  (I consider the days where we assume the brightness of a light bulb based on Watts consumed to be behind us.)